# handlebar register helper to do a mobile check

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, helper

Hi I am trying to switch templates based on a handlebar helper method

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("isMobile", function(){
   return typeof window.ontouchstart === "object";
});
```

and in template

```
{{isMobile}} --mobile template--
```

but this helper method does not work since i need something like

```
 {{#if}} this {{else}} that{{/if}}
```

I do not want to use {{#if mobile}}  since all data parsed and send to a backbone model and this is not relevant to modify the model during the parsing ..

thanks in advance for any suggestion/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use options.inverse as suggested [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html):

> Handlebars provides the block for the else fragment as
>   options.inverse.

So, rewrite your helper using **options.fn** and **options.inverse**.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("ifMobile", function(options){
    if ( typeof window.ontouchstart === "object" ) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Finally, your template should look like this:

```
{{#ifMobile}}
    <span>Mobile!</span>
{{else}}
    <span>Not mobile!</span>
{{/ifMobile}}
```